# Problem with PCL messages

Tags: pcl, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have encountered problem with the PCL messages, there is a number of messages:

```
pcl/ModelCoefficients
pcl/PointIndices
pcl/PolygonMesh
pcl/Vertices
```

but there is no makefile and the messages are not build. Meaning that they can't be used in the python. Why is that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52007/problem-with-pcl-messages/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are defined in Python.

What ROS distro are you using? For Groovy on Ubuntu, those files should be in **/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pcl/msg/**.

How did you import the message definitions? Something like this?

```
from pcl.msg import ModelCoefficients
```

Did you declare your dependency on the **pcl** package?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-01-13**:
I'm using Fuerte, the messages are defined in */opt/ros/fuerte/share/pcl/msg/* but not generated.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-01-13**:
I can confirm it: There are no python messages in the (ubuntu/debian) package ros-fuerte-pcl.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-01**:
Please post a bug ticket, specifying that the problem is in ROS Fuerte. The PCL issues page seems to be here: http://dev.pointclouds.org/projects/pcl/issues